# Twitter + Scribe + Cannot get String from a null object

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

I am trying to use scribe for authorization with twitter. When I try

```
requestToken = service.getRequestToken()
```

I get following error

```
14:10:11,305 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-4][IncludeTag:154]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get String from a null object
    at org.scribe.utils.Preconditions.check(Preconditions.java:80)
    at org.scribe.utils.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
    at org.scribe.utils.StreamUtils.getStreamContents(StreamUtils.java:20)
    at org.scribe.model.Response.parseBodyContents(Response.java:40)
    at org.scribe.model.Response.getBody(Response.java:66)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.login.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:2432)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

I tried the answer mentioned in following posts but nothing worked

**[scribe + twitter > Cannot get String from a null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417920/scribe-twitter-cannot-get-string-from-a-null-object)**

Whenever I am trying to include TwitterApi.SSL.class or TwitterApi.Authenticate.class, it is giving me "cannot be resolved to a type" error.

Did anybody experience this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Use .provider(TwitterApi.SSL.class) instead .provider(TwitterApi.class).
It should work.

Comment: I tried to use the given class but it is giving me following error

"TwitterApi.SSL cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 1):

Please check which Scribe version you are using. According to their ChangeLog page, SSL support was only added during version 1.2, so your jar will not contain the SSL class if it's from an older version.
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/changelog.txt

Downloading the latest jar will solve your problem :)